Carousel slider error 'firstIndex == 0 || childScrollOffset(firstChild!)! - scrollOffset <= precisionErrorTolerance
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        if (state.bumperBountyData.isNotEmpty)
                          CarouselSlider(
                            items: state.bumperBountyData.map((e) {
                              return Container(
                                height: 200,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            options: CarouselOptions(
                              enableInfiniteScroll:
                                  state.bumperBountyData.length > 1,
                              viewportFraction: 0.85,
                              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                state.bumperBountyCurrentIndex = index;
                                state.update([
                                  ProductBySectionController
                                      .bumperBountyListUpdate
                                ]);
                              },
                              aspectRatio: 1.3,
                              pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                              enlargeCenterPage: false,
                              disableCenter: false,
                              padEnds: !(state.bumperBountyData.length > 1),
                              autoPlay: state.bumperBountyData.length > 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),

CarouselSlider working very fine but the error keeps popping up in the debug console.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library
═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart': Failed
assertion: line 338 pos 12: 'firstIndex == 0 ||
childScrollOffset(firstChild!)! - scrollOffset <=
precisionErrorTolerance': is not true.


were you able to find a fix? I am facing the same error.

nope, error is still there even after upgrading flutter version and the dependency

I have made changes that fix the error and created a PR, it would help patching the issue if you comment on my PR. Here's the link.

I think the Carousel Slider being inside the Column is the reason for the
error. If you remove the Column, the error will go away, or you can wrap the
Carousel Slider with an Expanded or Flexible widget, or you can wrap it with a
SizedBox and specify its height.

i've tried everything that you mentioned but still no use, error is still there
